# Call a PHP function after Contact Form 7 submit

Tags: php, contact-form-7

Trying to run a script after a certain form has been submitted.

I'm using a simple echo just to check if it is working correctly but It isn't working.

```
function cspd_call_after_for_submit( $contact_data ){
$form_id = $contact_form->posted_data['_wpcf7'];
if ($form_id == 6) {
echo 'my script works'; exit();
}
```

}

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cspd_call_after_for_submit' );

There is no output.

Comment: The echo will probably be in the console and not on the screen as you are expecting.